# Use Firefox's localStorage inspector to edit cookies?

Tags: firefox, cookies

I'm performing a security analysis of my website and want to see how modified session data will effect my code. I can use Firefox's native Storage tab (on the developer tools menu) to view the cookie I want to change, but I can't edit it. Does Firefox allow this out of the box or do I need a plugin?

Answer (score 9):

This is not possible with the stock storage inspector as of Firefox 38.

It is planned to implement that feature, though: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1031192

---

You can use the [developer toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI):

- Press Shift+F2
- Type `cookie list`, press return
- Type `cookie remove PHPSESSID`, press return

Comment: `cookie set <name> <value>` is also awesome!

Comment: 'cookie list' shows zero cookies for me in anonymous mode, is this by design?

Comment: @MSpreij You can only see cookies from current tab (that is a very good idea)

Comment: Awesome answer, just what I wanted :)

Comment: @greuze yes, but it also shows zero cookies for me in a tab with a page which definitely has cookies, from looking at the inspector -> traffic -> headers.

Comment: Link broken (old, no surprise).