# Prevent cookies being edit through Firefox inspector

Tags: firefox, cookies

Currently, I have two cookies for logging in called:

1. Username: which contains the username the user-provided.
2. LogID: a 64-128 character long string contains all kinds of characters (uppercase, numbers, symbols, etc) hashed. The not-hashed version is begin stored in the DB. Used to see if you are already logged in.

Now I can modify Username and LogID when looking in my inspector under the storage tab-> cookies.
Here one can modify the date of LogID or the username itself. One can modify the LogID date to infinity requiring that one never has to log in again. To prevent this, I also store time in the database to see if the cookie is still valid.

[Use Firefox's localStorage inspector to edit cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347538/use-firefoxs-localstorage-inspector-to-edit-cookies)
This post says that it is not possible to edit cookies, but now it is. Is there any way/setting to use to prevent client form editing cookies through inspectors? I used the secure flag, thinking it would help, but doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question you linked, it was not possible to do it through Firefox, but a determined user could go into the cookie file on the local machine and edit it manually.

What you are describing is not possible due to the very fact that users have control over cookies.  Let's say you were able to prevent the cookie from being modified.  A simple `curl` request would completely circumvent your setup.

Instead, on the server side, you should be validating their cookies on every request.

In cookie-based authentication, you should send a completely random text that uniquely identifies the user.  That text should then be checked against the database to see if the cookie is still valid and if so, continue processing the request.

It is vitally important that the random text is both random and unique.  It should not be guessable or you'll have a user be able to take someone else's session.

That being said, it sounds like LogID is doing exactly this.  Even if the user changes the cookie, your database would see that the LogId doesn't belong to the User and shouldn't let them continue with their request.